# Error running app module is not found

Tags: java, android

I have merge my code on source tree after push and pull app folder is not showing in the project and this error is coming:[image]

Comment: attache image of your project folder structure ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check that you have a module build.gradle as well as the app's build.gradle and the settings.gradle
2. Sync Gradle - Use option "Sync Project with Gradle files"
   [image]
3. Then check that the Gradle plugin version is the latest one.

   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'